# Pause revolution slider on Video play

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is there a way to pause a revolution slide when video slide is being played.

The slider stops if the mouse is hovered over.

But I want the slider to stop on video play.

Kindly assist.

Here is my Code Snippet

```
var tpj=jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function() {

if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
    tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

    var api = tpj('.fullwidthbanner').revolution(
        {
            delay:9000,
            startwidth:1170,
            startheight:580,

            onHoverStop:"on",                       

            thumbWidth:100,                         
            thumbHeight:50,
            thumbAmount:3,

            hideThumbs:200,
            navigationType:"none",              
            navigationArrows:"solo",                

            navigationStyle:"round",                


            navigationHAlign:"center",              
            navigationVAlign:"bottom",                  
            navigationHOffset:30,
            navigationVOffset:-40,



            soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
            soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
            soloArrowLeftHOffset:0,
            soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

            soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
            soloArrowRightValign:"center",
            soloArrowRightHOffset:0,
            soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

            touchenabled:"on",                      
            timer:"on",


            stopAtSlide:-1,                         
            stopAfterLoops:-1,                       

            hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               
            hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    


            fullWidth:"on",

            shadow:0                                

        });

});
```

Comment: Have you referred http://clapat.ro/themes/creative/doc/rev-documentation.html#!/publicapi

Comment: @Sreekesh Okky Yes, I checked the given link, but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Share the code you tried in jsfiddle or something. No one is gonna writer code for you from scratch

Comment: @Sreekesh Okky Please check the updated question